# Need reference on the usage of bist commands

Tags: u-boot

I have an embedded device that has bist on it. During boot up I can stop in uboot and get into bist. When I do `help`here I see a list of commands. I am however unable to use them because there is not much help on how to use them. Does anybody know how to bist commands?

This is what I am talking about:

```
bist > help
?       - alias for 'help'
autoscr - DEPRECATED - use "source" command instead
base    - print or set address offset
boot    - boot default, i.e., run 'bootcmd'
check   - perform MMC CRC32 check
cmp     - memory compare
coninfo - print console devices and information
cp      - memory copy
crc32   - checksum calculation
diag    - perform board diagnostics
echo    - echo args to console
go      - start application at address 'addr'
halt    - halt board
help    - print online help
i2c     - I2C sub-system
idme    - idme    - Set nv ram variables
iminfo  - print header information for application image
itest   - return true/false on integer compare
loadb   - load binary file over serial line (kermit mode)
loads   - load S-Record file over serial line
loady   - load binary file over serial line (ymodem mode)
loop    - infinite loop on address range
loopw   - infinite write loop on address range
md      - memory display
mm      - memory modify (auto-incrementing address)
mmc     - MMC sub system
mmcinfo - mmcinfo <dev num>-- display MMC info
mtest   - simple RAM read/write test
mw      - memory write (fill)
nm      - memory modify (constant address)
ocotp   - OCOTP sub system
panic   - panic halt
pass    - pass blink pass pattern on LED
pmic    - pmic    - PMIC utility commands
printenv- print environment variables
reset   - Perform RESET of the CPU
run     - run commands in an environment variable
setenv  - set environment variables
sleep   - delay execution for some time
source  - run script from memory
sspi    - SPI utility commands
version - print monitor version
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Uboot manual](http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/Manual), especially section 5. It should also be possible to show additional information in the cli itself via `help COMMAND`